# MySql Error Code: 2006

Tags: mysql

Bom dia,

Estou usando o banco MySql WorkBeanch 6.3.5, a conexão está ok, porém quando faço um select simples em qualquer tabela o dá o seguinte erro:

Error Code: 2006. MySQL server has gone away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema pode ser na configuração do MySQL. No arquivo my.cnf no Linux ou my.ini no Windows procure e deixe esta linha assim:

```
[Mysqld] 
max_allowed_packet = 16 M
```

Aumentando a capacidade de `max_allowed_packet` no my.cnf (em [mysqld]) para 8 ou 16M corrige isto.

Comment: Onde fica esse arquivo ? To procurando e não aencontro

Comment: achei o arquivo, alterei e funcionou eu to usando o windows então no caso é my.ini. obrigado!